# Epoch to date conversion in javascript giving wrong answer

Tags: javascript

I am using `Date` to convert unix milliseconds epoch to a date.

So `1501783442 == Tuesday, 8 August 2017 12:35:57`.

But javascript says its
`Sun Jan 18 1970 14:39:43 GMT+0530 (IST)`.

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var d = new Date(1501783442);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

Jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t9wycmtb/).

Whats going on here?

Comment: Isn't Unix timestamp in seconds?

Comment: `Date.now()` (eg `1502197442246`) has three additional digits. Try multiplying by 1000...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, `1501783442` equals `GMT: Thursday, August 3, 2017 6:04:02 PM` according to https://www.epochconverter.com/.

Second of all, Unix uses *seconds* whereas Javascript uses *milliseconds*. So in order to convert, you must multiply by 1000, which then gives the correct result (corrected for the timezone that your browser lives in):

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var d = new Date(1501783442 * 1000);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  var d = new Date(1501783442);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```